# Can I use Instruments to profile BLE traffic?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, instruments

I am new to the macOS Instruments app and learning to use it to profile my app. I really want to profile the BLE traffic. Can I use Instruments to do so? Is support for this traffic built in or must I write a custom template?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If you click the Add button in the Instruments window toolbar, you can see all the available instruments. That should let you know if Instruments has an instrument to profile BLE traffic.